# The river bank is fully covered with reeds or?

Tags: adjectives

I want to describe a river bank which has a lot of reeds, to the extent that I can see nothing else but reeds on the bank, till now I only came up with:

> The river bank is fully covered with reeds

Is this sentence correct, and is there a much more beautiful way to say that?

> When the wind blows, the rustling of the reeds is very **good**

I need to replace this adjective too, to convey such a feeling that I love listening to the rustling?

Comment: I like your sentence the way it is. It sounds very nice. About your rustling, I think you can write *the rustling [...] is very nice* or *[it] is very pleasant*.

Comment: Reeds grow in marshes, bogs, and other wet areas ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_%28plant%29),[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_bed)).  They do not grow on the banks of rivers.  River banks are earth, rocks, etc alongside a river ([3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_bank)) and are elevated slightly above the river.

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder (or, in this case, in the mind of the reader). That said, _riverbank_ can be written as a single word; I would recommend that change. Also, I don't think you need to say "fully covered" – if something is "covered," it's (by default) "fully" covered. I prefer: _The riverbank is covered with reeds._ Perhaps even better: ***The riverbank is overgrown with reeds***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence looks perfect as is. However I have some alternatives:

"There were reeds all over the river bank"

"At the river bank, all I could see were reeds"

For the second one, you could say:

"When the wind blows, the rustling of the reeds is very soothing"